# linking proportional abundance to binary response variable

Tags: modeling, biostatistics, compositional-data

I ran into an issue that is simple in appearance but that got me somewhat stuck. I post it here to see if anybody has an elegant solution.

I have a dataset giving 1) the proportional abundance of five categories in several groups, and 2) whether the group exhibits a particular property (yes or no, binary variable).

You can think of this as a data set containing ecological communities observed on several islands. Each community is made up of five species (species proportions add up to 1 for all communities). The data set also contains a binary variable describing whether these communities persisted during the course of an experiment.

From this data set I want to estimate the effect of increasing the abundance of any given species on the probability of survival. The difficulty is that you have to correct for the decrease in all remaining species that is associated with an increase in any particular species. There is also the problem of having 5 species contributing to the survival of the community, but the community composition can only be described with a maximum of 4 variables.

Here is a script to generate the type of data I wish to analyse. Here all is random of course.

```
library(vegan)
species.a <- rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 100)
species.b <- rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 100)
species.c <- rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 100)
species.d <- rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 100)
species.e <- rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 100)
survival <- rbinom(size = 1, n = 1000, p = 0.5)

dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(decostand(cbind(species.a, species.b, species.c,
                                               species.d, species.e), 
                                         MARGIN = 1, method = 'total'), survival))
```

Comment: A standard approach would be logistic regression. However, your data matrix (e.g. $F_{ij}=$fractional abundance of species $j$ on island $i$) will exhibit (perfect)[multicollinearity](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multicollinearity/info), due to the unit row-sums. This means you will not be able to estimate species-specific coefficients in the standard way. Two choices to deal with this would be 1) dimension reduction, (e.g. [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression)), or 2) regularization (e.g. [LASSO](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/lasso/info)).

Comment: I don't understand why dimension reduction would be a solution. Since the variables are highly correlated, it's not very interesting to run a PCA. `scpca=rda(dataset[,1:5]);head(summary(scpca));biplot(scpca,choices = c(1,2))`. First you'll lose an axis because the last axis is deduced from the previous ones and the angle of the vectors are not meaningful. Plus, the eigenvalues are very small (`~4.0e-06`).